# How do I configure system properties on Tomcat 5.5 when configured as a server on Windows?

Tags: windows, tomcat

I need to get a -D settings into the picture in a tomcat deployment on Windows with Windows Server packaging. So there are no bat files (let alone .sh files) to add it to.

Does it work to edit them into catalina.properties?

Is there some other recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Windows system tray (bottom right corner next to the time) you should see an "Apache 6 Tomcat Service Configuration icon. Right click on this, click on the "Java" tab.  Fill out your -D settings in the Java Options section.  Doh. Just realized I have Tomcat 6.!   I checked it out in Tomcat 5.0 and it has the same option so that should work.